# Объекты нулевого размера и массивы нулевой длины

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, sizeof

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что стандарты `C` и `C++` говорят про объекты нулевой длины?

С одной стороны, все говорят, что размер объекта не может быть меньше единицы. То есть, даже если массив или объект - пустые, их размер все равно будет >= 1.

С другой стороны, все говорят, что создание массива, содержащего ноль элементов, - это законный процесс.

Но в то же время, существует требование, согласно которому адрес любого объекта не должен быть равен 0. Возможно, это не относится к требованию минимального размера объекта, но меня это дополнительно запутывает.

Comment: *"создание массива, содержащего ноль элементов, - это законный процесс"* Вроде, только если размер вычисляется во время выполнения.

Comment: Да, объект не может иметь нулевой размер.  Массив с нулевым размером не сможете создать, а можете объявить массив с нулевым размером в динамической памяти, что равносильно объявлению указателя, а указатель тоже является объектом и занимает память

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы не можете создать тип массива с нулевой длинной

> Its value N specifies the array bound, i.e., the number of elements in the array; **N shall be greater than zero**.

т.е.

```
int arr[0];//Ошибка.
```

Однако, возможно с помощью new-выражения создать массив без элементов:

> When the value of the expression is zero, the allocation function is called to **allocate an array with no elements**.

```
int * p = new int[0];//Ок
```

Речи о объектах нулевой длины в данном случае не идет, также, как и не идет речи об отсутствии выделения памяти или выделения нуля байт. new-выражение имеет право запросить памяти больше, чем требуется для элементов массива:

> When a new-expression calls an allocation function and that allocation has not been extended, the new-expression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type std​::​size_­t. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; **it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array and the allocation function is not a non-allocating form ([new.delete.placement])**.

Можно считать, что массив, создаваемый new-выражением - это не только элементы массива, но и некая служебная информация, например, размер массива. Тогда при выделении массива без элементов, будем иметь объект, в котором содержится только информация о пустом массиве. Естественно, обращаться к элементам такого массива нельзя, т.к. элементов нет.

В C++ типы действительно должны иметь ненулевой размер, поэтому класс, в котором нет подобъектов занимающих место, также имеет ненулевой размер:

> [Note: **Complete objects of class type have nonzero size**. Base class subobjects and members declared with the no_unique_address attribute (9.11.11) are not so constrained. — end note]

Однако, если объект такого класса является подобъектом базового класса, то его размер может быть равен нулю.

> [Note: A base class subobject might have a layout (6.6.5) different from the layout of a most derived object of the same type. A base class subobject might have a polymorphic behavior (10.9.4) different from the polymorphic behavior of a most derived object of the same type. **A base class subobject may be of zero size** (Clause 10); however, two subobjects that have the same class type and that belong to the same most derived object must not be allocated at the same address (7.6.10). — end note]

```
struct base {
};

struct derived: base {
    int x;
};

struct some{
    int x;
};

static_assert(sizeof(derived) == sizeof(some));
```